# Need an advice to implement an animation

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I have to implement the section from below image. When you click on one of those three section, the section will become almost full width, and two other section 10%, the animation should work like a fan.

I have never done something like that before but I know I can do with css and html. My question is what should I use, canvas? Or maybe will work highcharts?

Any resources will help. Thanks !

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TgeQ.jpg]

Comment: canvas could definitely be a good way to go. Depends on the complexity of the events you want to handle

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I need start to learn how to use canvas. In those boxes will be only some text added from wordpress.

Comment: Visually, your design looks like a pie chart with the outside of the pie clipped off. You might search Stackoverflow for canvas or SVG pie chart recipes.

Comment: I will, I have no ideea about canvas :d thank you !

Comment: Searching for canvas tutorials, I have found Bonsai library, I guess it will work. Is it right?